# Ruby on Rails, form_remote_tag, and Google Maps API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, google-maps

I am trying to add Google Maps to my page using YM4R/GM.  As a regular submit using `form_tag` everything works, so I know I didn't mess that part up.

But using `form_remote_tag` I end up with nothing inside my update div. I tested with rendering text so the right method is being executed and YM4R/GM is returning the Google Maps KML.  But the map is not being displayed.

My form tag:

```
<% form_remote_tag(:url => {:controller => "home", :action => "search"}, :update => "map_div") do %>
```

The search method specified as the form's action:

```
def search
    location = GeoKit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode(params[:address])
    @map = GMap.new("map_div")
    @map.control_init(:large_map => true,:map_type => true)
    @map.center_zoom_init([location.lat,location.lng],11)
    render :partial => 'map'
end
```

Is it correct to place the div to be updated inside of a partial, and then render that partial?

Am I overcomplicating this, or going about it the wrong way?  I know the YM4R/GM code is being executed as I see Google's KML output.  And I wonder if the problem is related the XML/KML response?  Is Rails interpreting the response as XML rather than HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fyi, I've just released a new version of gmaps4rails. It's based on Rails 3 and uses Google maps API V3:

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

Answer (score 0):

I'm working through this right now but I've got a feeling it's to do with Redirect vs Render. You see the map will work in a partial no problem when you refresh the page. 'Render' just recreates the view. Anyway, it's something I'm not very good at explaining this but there are [a few blogs](http://www.helloworlder.com/?p=6) on the topic. Apologies if this isn't really an answer. I'm working through it too so I'll post when I figure something out.

Comment: Worth taking a look here too: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render